# Wide to long with multiple variables

Tags: r

I'm looking for some help with transforming wide to long when there are two nested variables (B and R) with repeating targets (Item1, Item2, and Item3) in R. And there are some between-subject variables (e.g., X).

[image]

or

`x <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3),X = c(2.4,2.3,2.1),Item1_B = c(24,15,31),Item2_B = c(54,66,23),Item3_B = c(23,24,65),Item1_R = c(.2,.3,.1),Item2_R = c(.4,.2,.6),Item3_R = c(.2,.4,.2))`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The one-step approach would be to use the keyword `".value"` in `names_to`

```r
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(x, starts_with("Item"), 
            names_pattern = "(\\d+)_(.*)",
            names_to = c("Item", ".value"))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#>      ID     X Item      B     R
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1   2.4 1        24   0.2
#> 2     1   2.4 2        54   0.4
#> 3     1   2.4 3        23   0.2
#> 4     2   2.3 1        15   0.3
#> 5     2   2.3 2        66   0.2
#> 6     2   2.3 3        24   0.4
#> 7     3   2.1 1        31   0.1
#> 8     3   2.1 2        23   0.6
#> 9     3   2.1 3        65   0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a two-step process, but the `tidyverse` experts will have a better approach!

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-(id:X),names_to=c("Item", "type"), names_sep="_",names_prefix = "Item") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="type", values_from="value")
```

Output:

```
     ID     X Item      B     R
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   2.4 1        24   0.2
2     1   2.4 2        54   0.4
3     1   2.4 3        23   0.2
4     2   2.3 1        15   0.3
5     2   2.3 2        66   0.2
6     2   2.3 3        24   0.4
7     3   2.1 1        31   0.1
8     3   2.1 2        23   0.6
9     3   2.1 3        65   0.2
```

Comment: You are already an expert yourself! :-)

Comment: @TarJae perhaps I'll reconsider when/if I finally stop tripping on `names_pattern`!!

Answer (score 1):

Same as @Allan Cameron except using `names_pattern`:

```
pivot_longer(x, starts_with("Item"),
             names_pattern = '(.*)_(.*)', 
             names_to = c("Item", ".value")
             )
```

```
    ID     X Item      B     R
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   2.4 Item1    24   0.2
2     1   2.4 Item2    54   0.4
3     1   2.4 Item3    23   0.2
4     2   2.3 Item1    15   0.3
5     2   2.3 Item2    66   0.2
6     2   2.3 Item3    24   0.4
7     3   2.1 Item1    31   0.1
8     3   2.1 Item2    23   0.6
9     3   2.1 Item3    65   0.2
```